# Reduction of second order differential equation $u''=2u^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the differential equation $u''=2u^3$, what method of reduction can I use to make it easier to solve?

The reduction order method requires a solution to be known and I am unsure on where to go from here.

Comment: $u=0$ is a solution

Comment: another solution is $u(x)=x^{-1}$

Comment: I put my answer as a comment just for thoughts: Consider $u=x^n$, then $u"=n(n-1)x^{n-2}$ and $2u^3=2x^{3n}$. Now equating coefficients and exponents leads to essentially one possible value for $n$ which is $-1$ (In addition to $u=0$ as mentioned in the comments). Of course, this is not the entire solution, hence I deleted my post

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $2u'$ to get

$$2u'u''=4u^3u'$$ and by integration

$$u'^2=u^4+C.$$

Then a separable equation

$$\frac1{\sqrt{u^4+C}}=\pm dt.$$

Unfortunately, this one is difficult.

Comment: @LutzL:  indeed $2$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$u''=2u^3\to\\2u'u''=4u'u^3\to\\(u')^2=u^4+C_1\to\\u'=\pm\sqrt{u^4+C_1}$$can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***

$$u''=2u^3$$
$$\frac {d u'}{dx}=2u^3$$
$$\frac {d u'}{du}\frac {du}{dx}=2u^3$$
$$\frac {d u'}{du} u'=2u^3$$
$$\int u'{d u'} = 2\int u^3 du$$
$$ \frac {(u')^2} 2 = \frac {u^4} 2+K$$
$$  {(u')^2}  = {u^4} +K$$

The integration of this equation is not that simple.